# Function call to return string inside ListView_SetItemText macro

Tags: c++, winapi

A question on ListView_SetItemText macro for setting text of items in ListView Windows control.
Why does the following code works (in a sense that the text is displayed in the ListView)

```
std::string strNumber = NumberToString(number);
ListView_SetItemText( hListView, iItemIndex, iSubitemIndex, (LPSTR)strNumber.c_str() );
```

while a direct call doesn't

```
ListView_SetItemText( hListView, iItemIndex, iSubitemIndex, (LPSTR)NumberToString(number).c_str() );
```

where

```
std::string NumberToString ( double Number ) 
{ 
  std::ostringstream ss; 
  ss << Number; 
  return ss.str(); 
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the macro definition (in `commctrl.h`):

```
#define ListView_SetItemText(w,i,iS,s) \
{ \
    LV_ITEM _lvi;\
    _lvi.iSubItem=iS;\
    _lvi.pszText=s;\
    SNDMSG((w),LVM_SETITEMTEXT,i,(LPARAM)(LV_ITEM*)&_lvi);\
}
```

This expands to:

```
    ...
    _lvi.pszText=(LPSTR)NumberToString(number).c_str();
    SNDMSG((hListView),LVM_SETITEMTEXT,iItemIndex,(LPARAM)(LV_ITEM*)&_lvi);
}
```

The `NumberToString` function returns a *temporary* `std::string`, which is deleted before the `SNDMSG` call. So `_lvi.pszText` points to thin air. (Your code would be perfectly safe if `ListView_SetItemText` were a genuine function call.)

Answer (score 0):

The first call you send in the pointer to the variable strNumber.

In the second call you send in the pointer to the returned value of the function which is undefined after call.